# how to addClass to its equal index .....(JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, indexing

```
<ul>
   <li>Index 0</li>
   <li>Index 1</li>
   <li>Index 2</li>
</ul>
<div>
     <a>Index 0</a>
     <a>Index 1 (If i click this this this i want to addClass to it to LI with the same index of this )</a>
     <a>Index 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can invoke jQuerys `.index()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/index/)</sup> method for that purpose. It returns the index relative the the siblings of the current node. To find the `li node` with the according index, use `.eq()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)</sup>

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $('ul li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('your_new_class');
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2rFn3/

*Referring to your comment*

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $('ul li').eq($(this).index()).addClass('your_new_class').siblings().removeClass('your_new_class');
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2rFn3/1/

Comment: thanks sir but what if i only want to addclass when i click to that specipic <a> then removes that class if i click another <a>

Comment: @user555600: that requires just two methods more to chain! God bless jQuery :o) I updated my answer.

Comment: hi sir one last favor please, how do i combine Addclass with fadeIn fadeOut effect

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a").click(function() {
   //Remove classes from other li (per comment)
    $("ul li").removeClass("class");

   //Now update the clicked item
   var length = $(this).prevAll().length;
   $("ul li:eq(" + length + ")").addClass("class");
});
```

Comment: thanks sir but what if i only want to addclass when i click to that specipic <a> then removes that class if i click another <a>

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can add an id on the div and the li to make it easier to select.

```
div#start and ul#target

$("div#start > a").bind("click dblclick",function(){
    $("ul#target:nth-child("+$(this).index()+")").addClass("whatever");    
});
```